# PHP fetch the value from JSON

Tags: php

I have the customer details in the following format

How do i fetch the customer id is '5' from the output.

```
json_decode(array)
```

Result:

```
stdClass Object (
    [5] => stdClass Object ( 
        [email] => siddareddy.vishnuvardhanreddy@gmail.com 
        [firstname] => vishnu 
        [lastname] => siddareddy 
    ) 
)
```

Comment: show your json and indent the code

Comment: That's not possible, if you use `true` for the second parameter, you get an array, not an object.

Comment: I need to get customer id from the result(with out 'true')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can cast it to an array and then get the first [key](http://php.net/manual/en/function.key.php):

```
$key = key( (array) $result_object );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$array = json_decode($json, true);

foreach ($array as $key => $value)
{
    echo $key; //or use $value array to get the rest of its info
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please note that your first line cannot yield the second line as output. The first line should return an array, while the second code block is an object.

You can loop through all keys and values of your Array/Object and get the '5' that way:

```
foreach( $decodedjson as $key => $val ) {
  #Key is: 5
  echo "Key is: {$key}";
  #Val['firstname'] is: vishnu
  echo "Val['firstname'] is: {$val['firstname']}";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to invert the array from id to that array from say, email to id:

```
$result = json_decode($array, true);
// Change email to something else if you want another key
$inversecopy = array_flip(array_map(function($val) { return $val['email']; }, $result));
```

[Example in phpfiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/irf-5cc)

Answer (score 0):

You can access the numeric property like this

```
<?php
$data = array(
    "5" => array(
        'email' => 'siddareddy.vishnuvardhanreddy@gmail.com',
        'firstname' => 'vishnu',
        'lastname' => 'siddareddy'
    )
);
$json = json_encode($data);
$obj = json_decode($json);
var_dump($obj->{5}->email);
```

`$obj->{5}->email`, this the trick.